# Drupal changes language after clicking html link

Tags: i18n-l10n

Based on the internationalisation module i have my site set up in two languages.

My problem is when ever i click a link which i created with html.
e.g.

```
<a  href="mypage"  >link</a>
```

As soon as i arrive on my page after clicking the link, the language will change.

I have tried:

```
<a  href="en/mypage"  >link</a>
```

However then drupal changes the link to:

```
<a  href="en/en/mypage"  >link</a>
```

resulting in a page not found.

What should i add to my html link to stay in the selected language?

Comment: Didn't you force the user to be redirected to its default language or any of the languages?

Comment: Under admin/config/regional/language/configure
i have selected: the url, the request session, the users language and the sites default language, to be detected.
I wouldn't know any other way to force a user to its default language...

Comment: change the session to the url postfix, like example.com/fr

Comment: How/Where can i change this?

Comment: from *admin/config/regional/language/configure/url* select `Path prefix` and from *admin/config/regional/language/configure* select URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unchecked all the options on admin/config/regional/language/configure except the url
option.
Now my links `<a  href="en/mypage"  >link</a>` seems to work.
Credits to drupalist:
thanks

Comment: I'm using base_path() method and it takes the user back to default language. Can you please help me on it?